# I did everything but my object doesnt get rigified and it doesnt move with the rig

Tags: armature, rigify

[image]

i downloaded an .obj formatted NAO robot from sketchfab and i am trying to rig it. I watched every video, i looked at every possible error and i am 99% sure i did everything rght. its been 2 days and i cant still rig it. i can create a rog but my object doesnt move with it (i did all the parenting stuff). please help me i am literally losing my mind.

Comment: Pleae share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ (if it's under 30Meg in size) and follow the instructions on that page to add the link to the file here.

Comment: I cant use it becasue it is 37 mb and i deleted all i could even the rig, there is the robot and the armatur. i scaled them now still no change. how can i make it 30mb?

Comment: Any materials you can delete from it? You'll have to use another sharing site like the free version of wetransfer if you still can't reduce the size enough.

Comment: Just a thought: Go into Edit mode with your model selected, Hit 'A' to select all, then hit 'M' > Merge by Distance. Watch the bottom status bar when you do that and see if it reports any merged vertices. That can considerably reduce the size of a file, especially if it was produced in other software, and it might even cure your rigging problem.

Comment: I tried doing that and it didnt solve the problem. also the rig looks weird all the time. i deleted it. does this link work ? https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d2ebe1a83754e2fd0e18e24dd8774eb820230709223636/9a752d06073b42c25b410803d975eb5020230709223657/8169f2?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid

Comment: i also tried mixamo.. i tried everything. i am literally going crazy ...:(

Comment: I think the topology of that model is too high for rigify to cope with and there were also 1478 duplicate vertices on the model.. In addition you didn't apply the scale to your model or the armature (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode on both) and your armature isn't symmetrical. I don't have time to investigate any further I'm afraid.

Comment: I used the meta human armature and tried to adjust it.. what are duplicate vertices, are they a problem? and what do you mean by topology, this model won’t work? i’ve seen so many much complex chracters getting rigged. thank you for your answers i really appreciate it….

Comment: As I suggested in a previous comment you should have tried " Hit 'A' to select all, then hit 'M' > Merge by Distance." to get rid of the duplicate vertices. In fact it didn't help  in this case but can sometimes stop the armature working completely. I can't really add anythnig further apart from suggesting that you start again from scratch, use the Basic > Basic Human (Metarig) armature and turn on the symmetrise option in Edit mode before moving bones around.